# Disable "Invalid GET Data" Error

Tags: url, get

I have a site that's being ported to ExpressionEngine as a temporary stopgap while a longer term strategy is worked out. The issue is that there are URLs in Google (and the wild) that have "bad" query strings from the previous (Java) build so when a user visits a URL from the old site they get a generic "Invalid GET Data" error.

Is there a way to allow for those characters in an ExpressionEngine URL?

Comment: What version of EE is the site running?

Comment: It's 2.5.2 (since 2.5.3 is so damn buggy!)

Comment: I wish they would just remove this pointless error. EE shouldn't fall apart when given perfectly valid query strings.

Answer (score 11):

You can enable specific characters by going to your EE config/config.php file.

Find the **permitted_uri_chars** config variable.

Here is the default:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\\-';
```

Additionally, you may want to take a look at the **enable_query_strings** config too. You want to change it to:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Justin recommends, open up `system/expressionengine/core/EE_Input.php`, and find the `preg_match()` call at the end of the `filter_get_data()` function. Any semi-colons or question marks (encoded) in your GET variables will cause you to be filtered.

Think about security before you edit this function, but I have found it to be necessary at times also.